# mysqli query not working

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I'm trying to learn more about MySQL databases and writing custom PHP scripts.

I've queried the WordPress database before and I'm comfortable adding custom tables, custom queries etc. But I've never created my own database before.

So far I've got a db called `simplecms`, with one table called `core` which has two columns, `core_name` and `core_value`. So far it has one row in it.

All I'm trying to do it echo out the value of this one row.

So far, I have this code:

[updated code]

```
<?php

// New Connection
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost','root','root','simplecms');

// Check for errors
if( mysqli_connect_errno() ) {
    echo mysqli_connect_error();
} else {
    echo('connected to db...<br /><br />');
}

// Create Query
$query = "SELECT core_value FROM core WHERE core_name='url'";

// Execute Query
if( $result = $mysqli->query($query) ) {

    // Cycle through results
    while($row = $mysqli->fetch_object($result)){
        echo $row->column;
    }

    // Free result set
    $result->close();

} else {

    printf("Error message: %s\n", $mysqli->error);

}

// Close connection
$mysqli->close();

?>
```

This returns: `Error message: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '\'url\'' at line 1`

Any ideas where I might be going wrong?

[update]

I've managed to get it working with some completely new code! I'm not 100% why this works, but here it is just incase:

```
<?php

// new Connection
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost','root','root','simplecms');

// check for errors
if( mysqli_connect_errno() ) {
    echo mysqli_connect_error();
} else {
    echo('connected to db...<br /><br />');
}


// create a prepared statement
if($query = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT core_value FROM core WHERE core_name='url'")) {

    // execute
    $query -> execute();

    // bind results
    $query -> bind_result($result);

    // fetch value
    $query -> fetch();

    // echo out results
    echo $result;

    // close the statement
    $query -> close();

}

// close mysqli
$mysqli -> close();



?>
```

Comment: Add in some error checking, and check the return value from your `query()` call - if the query is failing, you'll never know. At a guess, you'd need to wrap the `url` in your SQL in quotes to stop the database from treating it as a column name.

Comment: Put quotes around the url in your request

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT core_value FROM core WHERE core_name=url
```

From what you've said there is no url column so this query wont work. Use `'url'`.

In the future you'll be able to catch issues like this by examining `$mysqli->error` the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php) has examples.

Comment: Amended code to `'url'` and added an else to print out the error message. Still getting the issue though. Error message: "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '\'url\'' at line 1"

Comment: @lukeseager `real_escape_string` is intended to be used on parameters to a query and not the entire query. Remove this line and the query should work.

Comment: Remove the entire line? Or just the `real_escape_string` function?

Comment: Remove `$query = $mysqli->real_escape_string($query);`. See here for the use of `real_escape_string` http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php

Comment: Removed from code. Doesn't return an error now. But also no results. Very weird.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to get it working with some completely new code! I'm not 100% why this works, but here it is just incase:

```
<?php

// new Connection
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost','root','root','simplecms');

// check for errors
if( mysqli_connect_errno() ) {
    echo mysqli_connect_error();
} else {
    echo('connected to db...<br /><br />');
}


// create a prepared statement
if($query = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT core_value FROM core WHERE core_name='url'")) {

    // execute
    $query -> execute();

    // bind results
    $query -> bind_result($result);

    // fetch value
    $query -> fetch();

    // echo out results
    echo $result;

    // close the statement
    $query -> close();

}

// close mysqli
$mysqli -> close();



?>
```